# How do I work with query results - Javascript (Azure Database)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, azure, visual-studio-2013

so I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 with Apache Cordova at the moment and using Microsoft Azure as the backend database (New to this!). I have written the following code as a test and I can't seem to work with the results of a query. `alert(JSON.stringify(results))` seems to work and is alerting the query results as [{"id":"1234","username":"james","password":"james"}]. However, when I try to use results.length or results.'anything', it is not recognising results as an array. Is there a way I can work with the query results? Help is much appreciated :)

```
 function test() {

    //Query the Accounts table where the input fields match a record in the table.

    var query = accountsTable.where({
        username: textUsername.value,
        password: textPassword.value
    }).read().done(function (results) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(results));
        var queryTest = results[0].text;
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
}
```

[image: Here is what I get when i type is "results."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify property name, it seems you are specifying the **text**, which is not there.

For single record:

```
var query = accountsTable.where({
    username: textUsername.value,
    password: textPassword.value
}).read().done(function (results) {
    alert(results[0].id + " " + results[0].username + " " + results[0].password);
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

For multiple records:

```
var query = accountsTable.where({
    username: textUsername.value,
    password: textPassword.value
}).read().done(function (results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        alert(results[i].id + " " + results[i].username + " " + results[i].password);
    }
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});
```